# Class 'infobip\models\SMSRequest' not found

Tags: php, smpp, infobip

I am using infobip sample code in php for sms integration in my website.
Following error came when I try to send message uising oneapi-sample app on the following line:
$message = new SMSRequest();

Fatal error: Class 'infobip\models\SMSRequest' not found in /var/www/html/oneapi-php-master/oneapi-sample-app/send-message-action.php on line 15

Comment: provide details info

Comment: Did you even include the class?

Comment: yes, like this :   use infobip\models\SMSRequest;
use infobip\SmsClient;

Comment: Problem is fixed. Pull changes and run `$ composer install`

Answer (score 1):

Since your project is developed using php, you can have look into official php send sms class

http://phpclasses.org/package/9522-PHP-Send-SMS-messages-with-Spring-Edge-API.html

You can just include the class file which is using http api to send sms you can call function as below:

```
$classobj->sendsms($mobileno, message);
```

This is the easiest class to customize or integration with php. Currently this class is using a different sms api gateway. You can just change RestAPI URL and param to use with InfoBip.